# Why do I get a ClassCastException here?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Why is it not possible to cast o1 (C1 is superclass of C3) to C3 (subclass of C1)?

```
interface I1 { }
interface I2 { }
static class C1 implements I1 { }
static class C2 implements I2 { }
static class C3 extends C1 implements I2 { }
static class C5 extends  C1 implements  I2 {}




public static void main(String[] args) {
    C1 o1 = new C1();
    C2 o2 = new C2();
    C3 o3 = new C3();
    C5 o5 = new C5();
    o3 = (C3) o1;
}
```

Comment: Because o1 doesn't contain some of the implementation/information o3 has/required (which is inherited from I2), isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every C3 is a C1, but not every C1 is C3. You are trying to convert an instance of `C1` to `C3`.

Look this example from docs

```
Object x = new Integer(0);
System.out.println((String)x);
```